# Is it possible to search/browse music via the Sonos API

Tags: sonos

I'm building a sonos control application that should basically have the same functionality as the sonos app.
I'm using the API at https://developer.sonos.com/ and I am able to control a sonos speaker, play, pause etc. but I can't find how to search/browse music.
Does anyone know if this is possible and, if so, where do I find the commands?

(I know this has been asked before but that was over 3 years ago)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Cheers,
Robert.

Answer (score 0):

The Sonos Cloud API is too lame to offer content browsing and searching.

You use ContentDirectory.Browse per the UPnP documentation to enumerate and search everything except music service content.